# How to configure Traefik for AKS to use GRPC service on AKS?

Tags: grpc, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, traefik-ingress

I installed traefik on AKS but i don't know much about how to *configure Traefik for GRPC on K8s for Reverse Proxy and Dynamic Routing*.

Comment: Maybe you can follow the steps [here](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/user-guide/grpc/) to configure the gRPC for Traefik and then deploy to AKS.

Comment: I tried this but id didn't worked.